# Over 2500 tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

My application stores login information of over 2500 employees in a table named "emp_login".
Now I have to store the activities of every employee on daily basis. For this purpose i have created a separate table for every employee. E.g. emp00001, emp0002... Each table will have about 50 columns.
After digging in alot on stackoverflow I'm kind of confused. Many of the experts say that database having more than 200-300 tables on mysql is considered to be poorly designed.

My question is whether it is good idea to have such a bulk of tables? Is my database poorly designed? Should i choose other database like mssql? Or some alternative idea is there to handle the database of such applications??

Comment: Well that was a bad idea. Fix that. Then get back to us.

Comment: "For this purpose i have created a separate table for every employee" - why? Don't do that. Relational databases are built to handle tables with lots of rows, not lots of tables with few rows.

Comment: Yes, having so many tables is bad. You'll also have a great deal of difficulty both referencing and processing data you store in that way. You should read up on foreign keys and normalization https://www.guru99.com/database-normalization.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nothing to do with MySQL but to do with your design which is flawed. You should have one table for all your employees. This contains information unique to the employees such as firstname, lastname and email address.

```
|ID | "John"   | "Smith"    | "john.smith@gmail.com"        |
|1 | "James"   | "Smith"    | "james.smith@gmail.com"       |
|2 | "jane"    | "Jones"    | "jane.jones.smith@yahoo.com"  |
|3 | "Joanne"  | "DiMaggio" | "jdimaggio@outlook.com"       |
```

Note the ID column. Typicially this would be an integer with AUTO_INCREMENT set and you would make it the Primary Key. Then you get a new unique number every time you add a new user.

Now you have separate tables for every piece of RELATED data. E.g. the city they live in or their login time (which I'm guessing you want from the table name).

If it's a one to many relationship (i.e. each user has many login times), you create a single extra table which REFERENCES your first table. This is a DEPENDENT table. Like so:

```
| UserId | LoginTime              |
| 1      | "10:00:04 13-09-2018"  |
| 2      | "11:00:00 13-09-2018"  |
| 3      | "11:29:07 14-09-2018"  |
| 1      | "09:00:00 15-09-2018"  |
| 2      | "10:00:00 15-09-2018"  |
```

Now when you query your database you do a JOIN on the UserId field to connect the two tables. If it were only their LAST login time, then you could put it in the user table because it would be a single piece of data. But because they will have many login times, then login times needs to be its own table.
(N.b. I haven't put an ID column on this table but it's a good idea.)

If it's data that ISN'T unique to the each user, i.e. it's a MANY to MANY relationship, such as the city they live in, then you need two tables. One contains the cities and the other is an INTERMEDIARY table that joins the two. So as follows:

(city table)

```
| ID  | City          |
| 1   | "London"      |
| 2   | "Paris"       |
| 3   | "New York"    |
```

(city-user table)

```
| UserID   | CityID |
| 1        | 1      |
| 2        | 1      |
| 3        | 3      |
```

Then you would do two JOINS to connect all three tables and get which city each employee lived in. Again, I haven't added an ID field and PRIMARY KEY to the intermediary table because it isn't strictly necessary (you could create a unique composite key which is a different discussion) but it would be a good idea.

That's the basic thing you need to know. Always divide your data up by function. Do NOT divide it up by the data itself (i.e. table per user). The thing you want to look up right now is called "Database Normalization". Stick that into a search engine and read a good overview. It wont take long and will help you enormously.

Comment: You have put the stuffs very explicitly. Understood it thoroughly.

Comment: My database is one-to-many. This way my database is supposed to get a bulk entries of over 2500 rows everyday. 75k-80k entries every month. Is there any limitation of rows in mysql??

Comment: 75-80k entries per month is easily manageable. There are different types of table in MySQL. Use InnoDB when you create the tables. They can be hundreds of Gigabytes in size which is the actual limit. If you're happy with my answer can you accept it, please? :)

Comment: Make sure you add indexes to your ID columns. Indexes are important for good performance and are more important than how many rows you have.

Comment: If you're happy with this answer as you seem to be, can you accept it, please?

Comment: sorry i was so busy with my application that i forgot to accept the answer. can u clear one more of my doubts? while digging into myisam and innodb i found that people prefer myisam to innodb when it comes to faster performance. since my table is supposed to receive bulk entries, is it fine to use myisam for faster queries out of thousands of thousand of entries?

Comment: The information you've read is probably old. MyISAM was the standard table for MySQL for a long time and InnoDB used to have much worse performance. But InnoDB is the standard for MySQL these days. MyISAM *might* be slightly faster but InnoDB is very close and has a lot of good reasons to use it. MyISAM is mainly there for legacy reasons now. Use InnoDB. If you still find you need more performance there are better ways to speed it up than using MyISAM. I've worked on very big systems and InnoDB has been fine. Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 3):

Do -not- do it that way.  Every employee should be in 1 table and have a primary key index ID ie:

```
1: Tom
2: Pete
```

You then assign the actions with a column that references the employees ID number

```
Action, EmployeeID
```

You should always group identical entities in a table with index ids and then link properties / actions to those entities by Id.  Imagine what you would have to do to search a database that consisted of a different table for every employee.  Would defeat the whole point of using SQL.

Event table could look like:

```
Punchin, 1, 2018/01/01 00:00
```

That would tell you Tom punched In at 2018/01/01 00:00.  This is a very simple example, and you prob wouldn’t wanna structure an event table that way but it should get you on the right track.

Comment: Thanks mason. Can you give me some link of the tutorial through which i could learn more ideas on how to implement this method in my database?

Comment: This is based on a Q+D google but this looks like it does a decent job of explaining simple entity based data modeling without getting to technical http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/relational_database_design.html